# Decode datetime and lat long hexadecimal data received from gps tracker

Tags: c#, gps, latitude-longitude, datetime-format, hex

I have to develop c#.net gps server application for UM02 gps trackers. Data received via UDP in hexadecimal format. But it I can’t decode datetime and lat/long values. Please give me help to decode it

GPS tracker type : UM02
manufacture :  Uniguard Technology Limited

Here are some details from their protocal

**Server receives Sample data:**

34 00 08 00 01 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 1D 43 A2 9B E8 42 E6 25 20 42 4E 52 30 39 42 30 36 36 39 32 00 00 31 32 2D 30 33 2D 30 35 20 31 31 3A 34 37 3A 34 33 00

**Decode it one by one**

**34 00**                                   -   packet length = 0x34 = 52byte

**08 00**                   -   command ID=0x 0008

**01**                      -   1--GPS Fix   00--GPS do not fix

**09**                          -   Alarm

**00 00 00 00**                 -   speed = 0

**00 00 1D 43**                 -   direct

**A2 9B E8 42**                 -   Longitude

**E6 25 20 42**                 -   latitude

**4E 52 30 39 42 30 36 36 39 32 00 00**     -          [NR09B06692]

**31 32 2D 30 33 2D 30 35 20 31 31 3A 34 37 3A 34 33 00**   -    [12-03-05 11:47:43]

Comment: Do you even know what the Hex down there (for the datetime portion) converts to? My guess is that if you convert that to an int you'll find it's a Unix time stamp or ticks since 1970 or some other integer representation of time. Once you know that it gets a lot easier. Especially if the starting bytes or the length of that value are fixed.

Comment: [here is the hex part for date time  31 32 2D 30 33 2D 30 35 20 31 31 3A 34 37 3A 34 33 00] that value cant convert to int it is very large value

Answer (score 0):

here 2D stands for '-'
20 for space
3A for ':'
3 is just added to every plain int.remove it.for ex.3132 2D means '12-'
we get the plain.
at least in this example it works like this.